# inputStream to json

Tags: javascript, json

в js скрипт приходит json в формате inputstream
как мне его распарсить?

Comment: используйте JSON.parse()

Comment: @RomanPolshikov то есть то, что файлы хранятся в бд и приходят в виде inputstream не важно?
я просто не знаю, поэтому уточнить хочу